# SQLlite format date column as week numbers when week starts from Wednesday

Tags: sql, sqlite, date, date-conversion

in SQLite I have Table with time column:

```
TIME
2016/09/03
2016/09/10 
2016/09/12
```

I want to convert it to week numbers where a week starts from Wednesday
so I obtain:

```
TIME
35
36
36
```

when I use:

```
SELECT STRFTIME('%W', '2016-09-12', '-3 days' )
```

it works but when I try to put column name in place of the date, it returns a column of "None"

Please help, Thanks

Comment: Of course I use table name while attempting to convert
 SELECT STRFTIME('%W', TIME') FROM Table_Name

Comment: Update, I got it the problem was in details ' ' and [ ],
 it should be:
           SELECT strftime('%W', [TIME], '-2 days') FROM Table_Name;

Comment: You can delete the question.